# Removing strings from df column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working in a python3 jupyter notebook.

I'm trying to do some numerical calculations on a column in my dataframe which is made up of dollar amounts.  Some of the lines have "$-  " instead of numbers.  How do I tell python to ignore those rows so I can look at the valid data?

movie is my dataframe
revenue is the column I'm looking at

```
set(movie['revenue'])
```

I get this type of output:

```
{' $-   ',
 '1',
 '10',
 '100',
 '10000',
 '97250400',
 '98000000',
 '99000000'}
```

I've tried a few ways so far:

```
movie['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(movie['revenue'])

movie['revenue'] = movie['revenue'].astype(np.float64)
```

Nothing seems to work.  Please help!

Comment: It is a simple list, so why don't you just test all elements of the list, and remove them if you find a dollar symbol?

Comment: How would you do that exactly?  if else loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[' $-   '], ['1'], ['10'], ['100'],
                   ['10000'], ['97250400'], ['98000000'],
                   ['99000000']], columns=['A'])

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

df.dtypes

# A    float64
# dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I see going about handling this.

Given:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['12','$10','22','$99','100']})
df
    A
0   12
1  $10
2   22
3  $99
4  100
```

1) Coerce the values that `pandas.to_numeric(...)` can't convert to be Nans. This way most calculations will ignore them.

```
pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce')
0     12.0
1      NaN
2     22.0
3      NaN
4    100.0
```

2) Remove the `'$'` if present and convert to number so you are not loosing data.

```
df.A.apply(lambda i: float(i[1:]) if i[0] == '$' else float(i)) 
0     12.0
1     10.0
2     22.0
3     99.0
4    100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a mask to ignore those rows:

```
import pandas as pd
movie = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'revenue': [' $-   ','1','10','100','10000','97250400','98000000','99000000']
    }
)

print(movie[movie['revenue'].map(str.isdigit)])
#    revenue
#1         1
#2        10
#3       100
#4     10000
#5  97250400
#6  98000000
#7  99000000
```

[`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) returns `True` if all the characters in the string are digits.

So `movie['revenue'].map(str.isdigit)` will return a `pandas.Series` (mask) of the same length as `movie` with boolean values indicating if the value is a number or not.

Then `movie[movie['revenue'].map(str.isdigit)]` returns a new `pd.DataFrame` with only the rows where the mask is `True`.

**Update**

If you know ahead of time that the bad value will always be a specific string, for instance `' $-   '`, you can simply do the following:

```
movie[movie['revenue'] != ' $-   ']
```

This is faster because the logical operators are vectorized (AFAIK) and you can avoid calling `apply()` or `map()`.

**Update 2**

Yet another method from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern):

```
movie[~movie['revenue'].str.contains('\$')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution to remove from a list an element containing '$':

```
tmp = movie['revenue']
for elt in movie['revenue']:
    if elt.find('$') != -1:
        tmp.remove(elt)
movie['revenue'] = tmp
```